# How do I permanently reduce Grub waiting time?

Tags: boot, grub2, updates

I edited `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to reduce the Grub waiting time, but after recent update resets `grub.cfg` file to its initial state.

I know there is a way to make it permanent, but I don't know how. Please anyone advice.

(I tried to edit `/ect/default/grub`, but such a file does not exists in my system, 12.04 LTS)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I tried to edit `/ect/default/grub`

It's **`/etc/default/grub`**, it exists on every 12.04 system, and you must have root privileges to edit it.

- Use `Alt-F2`, then `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Don't forget to open a terminal (`Ctrl-Alt-T`) and run `sudo update-grub` to make the changes permanent!